# implementing garbage collector according to Modern Compiler implementation in ML

Tags: compiler-construction, garbage-collection, programming-languages

In Chapter 13 of Appel's Modern Compiler Implementation in ML, the book gives advice on how to construct a garbage collector for the Tiger programming language it defines. My question is about the `pointer map` the book describes, these pointer maps are basically information generated at each call site about the current roots of allocated blocks.

On page 288, it says "implement a temp-map with a boolean for each temporary: is it a pointer or not? Also make a similar map for the offsets in each stack frame, for frame-resident pointer variables."

Here `temp` refers to the unbounded number of temporaries that will later be colored into machine registers. What I don't understand is:

1. What's a good way to represent the temp-map? These temporaries are later colored into machine registers, which means they refer to roots of allocated blocks that might only live in registers and not on the stack. But the values of these temps are known until runtime. **How can I let the collector know which register holds a potential root?**
2. Even with a proper representation, let's say somehow the collector knew that there are potential roots living in `ebx` and `edx` at this call site after reading in the pointer map. The collector, in getting that information, has done some computation, and might have overwritten the values in `ebx` and `edx` ! **How is the collector supposed to retrieve potential roots from registers if it needs to do some computation in the first place to determine what registers holds roots?**

Comment: Re 2),  a collector that overwrites data isn't going to be very popular. Better use one that knows how the registers of a suspended thread are saved.